# No newlines in template file

Tags: php

So i am writing an open source software written in PHP and i am going to use a template system. The templates will be stored on the hard drive.

I tried this method, however all the html that is in the files gets displayed in just one line, while in the files itself it is on a few lines.

Why is that?

Comment: might have to share some code here..

Comment: How are you reading the template file? Some functions automatically remove newlines. Can you give us a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's likely happened is that whatever you're viewing the source put it all on one line and ignored the linebreaks added in by whatever editor you use.

It could also be the editor you're using to edit the included file. There's actually several different ways of marking an end-of-line (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) Wikipedia article) but the two most common are Windows (`\n\r`) and *nix (`\n`). Check your file settings within your editor to see if it could be an issue. Most anything is compatible with both, but it's definitely worth taking a look. The *nix version is my personal choice, even those I'm a Windows user.

Comment: Well, adding \n or \n\r didn't really do anything...i even tried another editor.

Comment: Most editors detect the end-of-line types of a file. If you're not using the console to view the output, try running it from console (php myfile.php) to see what the output looks like. You can also use something like Notepad++ (and I'm sure plenty of other editors have the same feature) to view EOLs.

Comment: Yup it was the editor Notepad++. I used the integrated Notepad in Windows and everything was displayed as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the `\n` in HTML you want, it won't do anything.

I suspect you're looking for `<BR>`

Comment: I am talking that the html itself get's displayed in one line. And there really is no code to display, because at the moment it is just an include() of a text file with html code.

Comment: Well, it doesn't. Because there is no code to remove newlines.

Comment: @user628445: well, it does, because there is no newlines.

Comment: How many times do i have to say that all i do is include the file? There is no preg_match to add OR remove newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is including a plain text file and displaying it with php, then it's going to be interpreted as html, regardless of whether or not there's any tags in it. All whitespace in html is displayed as just a single space, so all your text is ending up on one line. 2 possible solutions: convert the line-endings in your text to html using `nl2br()` or force a content-type of plaint-text using `header("Content-Type: plain/text");`